# Include between navbar and vertical menu

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently creating my first website and i have some trouble, i want to include a page between a navbar and a vertical bar, and i want to change to page to include when a click on a button of my vertical bar. Here is a screen :
[Screen of my Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INu9q.png)

And here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Memeable | The 1# world meme generator</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div >
    <?php
        include("head.php");
    ?>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is my head.php :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Memeable</a>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook "></a>
  <a href="http://www.twitter.com" class="fa fa-twitter "></a>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="" id = "first">Premier</a>
  <a href="#" class = "">Deuxième</a>
  <a href="#" class = "">Troisième</a>
  <a href="#" class = "">Quatrième</a>
</div>
```

I'm sure that the solution is easy but i don't see how to do. 
Thank you for your help !

Comment: You want to display head.php when a button is clicked? what button?

Comment: is it a single page application?

Comment: When  a button of a vertical menu ("Premier, deuxième etc...)

Comment: It is better if it's a single page app but not necessary

Comment: The head.php will only display if you click the premier etc. links correct?

Comment: No, the head.php is juste the navbar and the vertical menu, i want when i click on a button in the vertical menu that in the red zone show on my screen a page includes

Answer (score 0):

To show your content in your "content area" use [`include`](http://www.php.net/include). You provide the file name you want to load as an argument. Use an array to specify all the valid files you want to use, then use a [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) parameter to select the correct sub page to load.

```
<?php
$files = array();
$files['home'] = 'home.php';
$files['contact'] = 'contact.php';
$files['whatever'] = 'you_want.php';
?>
```

Then later at the location where you want the content to be displayed use the following code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['nav'], $files[$_GET['nav']])) {
    include $files[$_GET['nav']];
} else {
    include $files['home']; // default page
}
?>
```

To "call" the right sub page add the `?nav=...` query parameter to your URLs like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?nav=home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?nav=contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```